# How to define interface according to the keys provided by Map?

Tags: typescript

I'm new to Typescript.

I want extract a class called Mapper.
This mapper takes two parameters:
1. The object data we want to map
2. The Map that defines the shape of data after map

And it has methods that will return a MappedData according to what kind of mapping we wants to do.

```js
class Mapper {
  constructor(data: Data, dataMap: Map) {

  }

  mapKey(): MappedKeyData {
    // return a mappedKeyData
  }
}

// Usage
const source = {
  Name: "Dudi"
}
const map = new Map([
  ['name', 'Name']
])
const mapper = new Mapper(source, map)
console.log(mapper.mapKey()) // {name: 'Dudi'}
```

The question is that I want to ensure the type of MappedKeyData is an interface that has all the keys that defined after key mapping. (according to the keys defined in the map)

For example:

```
interface MappedKeyData {
  name: 'string'
}
```

Is this the right way to use Typescript? If yes, how to implement this? Thanks...

Comment: And what happens when a property of `source` is not named in `map` and vice versa?  Like, `new Mapper({a: 1}, new Map(["b": "c"]))`?

Comment: Also it's strange that `map` has entries where the *key* is the desired *output* key and the *value* is the desired *input* key.  I'd think it would be the reverse.  But it all depends on what you want to see in edge cases where the map does not correspond to the source.

Comment: Finally, why do you want a `Map` at all if the keys are just strings?  Wouldn't a plain old object like `{name: "Name"}` be easier and more straightforward?  TypeScript has very good support for keeping track of the key-value relationship in a plain object type (e.g., `{x: number, y: boolean}`), but it treats `Map` as little more than a dictionary type (e.g., `{[k: string]: number | boolean}`).

Comment: Hmm... let's pretend `source` must be named in Map.
The goal I want to achieve is to write a key replacer in Typescript.
So if I have an object `{name: 'Dudi'}`, I can replace the key index to `{'NAME": 'Dudi'}`, but I don't know how to write it properly. As long as the key replace can work, any kind of Map is fine. Do you know how to do it? @jcalz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want to use classes and `Map` objects you can, but it would be more straightforward just to use a function and a plain old javascript object.
I will show one way to do that, and you can adapt it if you need to (but be warned that `Map` in TypeScript isn't strongly typed the way you want so I'd avoid it).

Here is the `mapKeys()` function:

```
function mapKeys<D extends object, M extends Record<keyof M, keyof D>>(
  data: D,
  dataMap: M
) {
  const ret = {} as { [K in keyof M]: D[M[K]] };
  (Object.keys(dataMap) as Array<keyof M>).forEach(
    <K extends keyof M>(k: K) => {
      ret[k] = data[dataMap[k]];
    }
  );
  return ret;
}
```

And here is the basic usage of it:

```
const mapped = mapKeys(
  {
    Name: "Dudi",
    Age: 123
  },
  { name: "Name", age: "Age" }
);
// const mapped: {
//    name: string;
//    age: number;
// }
console.log(mapped); // {name: 'Dudi', age: 123}
```

The way `mapKeys()` works at runtime is simply to loop through the keys `k` of `dataMap` and set the analogous property in the return object to be the data from `data` at key `dataMap[k]`.  So that's the `ret[k] = data[dataMap[k]]` line.

The rest of it is mostly type annotations and assertions to help the compiler understand and verify what we are doing.  Given that `data` is of type `D` and `dataMap` is of type `M`, the return type will be the [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#mapped-types) `{[K in keyof M]: D[M[K]] }`.  This is saying that it will have the same keys as `M`, and the value for each key `K` will be of type `D[M[K]]` (that is, we [look up](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-1.html#keyof-and-lookup-types) the `K` property of `M`, and then look up *that* property of `D`).

So that should work for you, depending on your use case.

---

Of course there are a bunch of caveats; I tried to ask what you wanted to see in some of these cases, and all I know for sure is that you don't want it to be possible to put a value in `dataMap` if it's not a key of `data`.  The [constraint](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html#generic-constraints) `M extends Record<keyof M, keyof D>` should guarantee that.  But there are other possible edge cases:

#### STRONGLY TYPED `dataMap`

First of all, the `dataMap` param has to be fairly strongly typed for this to work.  If you just do this:

```
const source = { Name: "Didu", Age: 321 };
const map = { name: "Name", age: "Age" };
```

Then the `map` will end up being inferred as type `{name: string, age: string}` and not `{name: "Name", age: "Age"}`.  And you'll get an error:

```
const badInfer = mapKeys(source, map); // error!
// ┌───────────────────────────> ~~~
// └─ Argument of type '{ name: string; age: string; }' is not assignable
//    to parameter of type 'Record<"name" | "age", "Name" | "Age">'.
```

The way to fix this is to make sure that `dataMap` has [string literal](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#string-literal-types) property values, such as you get when you use a [`const` assertion](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#const-assertions):

```
const fixedMap = { name: "Name", age: "Age" } as const; //
// inferred to be {readonly name: "Name"; readonly age: "Age"; }
const fixedInfer = mapKeys(source, fixedMap); // okay, right type now
```

Do note that if we used a `Map` instead of an object, the [default TypeScript type declarations for it](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/v3.5.3/lib/lib.es2015.collection.d.ts#L21-L29) are not strong enough.  A `Map<K, V>` means that potentially any key in `K` could map to any value in `V`.  And so `new Map([["name","Name"],["age","Age"]])` would, at best, end up equivalent to the type `{name: "Name" | "Age", age: "Name" | "Age"}`, and you'd have an unfortunate `string | number` in your output type.

#### LEAVING OUT PROPERTIES

Nothing stops you from leaving some of the keys in `data` out of `dataMap`:

```
const fewerProps = mapKeys({ Name: "Dodi", Age: 132 }, { name: "Name" });
// const fewerProps: { name: string }; // no age
console.log(fewerProps); // {name: "Dodi"}
```

#### DUPLICATED PROPERTIES

Nothing stops you from mapping the same key in `data` multiple times in `dataMap`:

```
const duplicateProps = mapKeys(
  { Name: "Dido", Age: 231 },
  {
    name: "Name",
    alsoName: "Name",
    age: "Age",
    alsoAge: "Age"
  }
);
// const duplicateProps: {name: string; alsoName: string; age: number; alsoAge: number;}
console.log(duplicateProps); // {name: "Dido", alsoName: "Dido", age: 231, alsoAge: 231}
```

#### INDEX SIGNATURES WILL DO WEIRD THINGS

If your `data` object has an [index signature](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#indexable-types) the type system will behave strangely, since it will assume `data` has any possible key that matches the index:

```
const dictionary: { [k: string]: string | number } = { Name: "Didi", Age: 312 };
const confused = mapKeys(dictionary, {
  dogs: "Dogs",
  cats: "Cats",
  age: "Age"
});
// const confused: { dogs: string | number; cats: string | number; age: string | number;}
console.log(confused); // {dogs: undefined, cats: undefined, age: 312 }
// note that "undefined" can sneak into index signatures
```

That's not a perfect outcome, since the type system says `confused` has a `dogs` property of type `string | number`, but it's actually `undefined` at runtime.  This is one of the pitfalls of index signatures, and our mapper falls into it.

---

Some of those caveats can be worked around if you decide what you'd like to see and put in more complex type assertions and annotations, but I think I'll stop here and leave any patching-up to you.  This should hopefully be enough to give you some direction.  Good luck!

[Link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAWwIYAcDSBTAngZwB4ARRbADymzABN9E4AjAK22gBpEBZMy6uxACU2cAE41CAazxxg3TtNyzExAHyqAFAChEiGqiioAXCvY69B1FwwmuWgJSIA3uYgJ8URKOyeAvM4BfRFR6J0QAbUxEGCRFZS4AXRNicK5IhITEAIBucw0AeRY2KAA6RXwNfUNrdEcQxABBUVFUXCkZOS5VexLgMQBRVAgAC21dXUIoiipaejjOzUkTTEdfVWdzca8fcMlM-yrUcMOa3YzcrYDzewvtqBBRJG8oXKutAHp3xAAhEJgIRAgfCoADm2C0WjcYA8KAw6GwNEQ-jQWDwFXMLi2ADlUMhsCYAETEEA0GAEsxbBpgkwARgATABmcwBCnORBgXH4xAEnF48nBancqnYAlZBy5T6IKEwlHwmgmFyS8YcvEmDyiGIgiVfcagrlgEDIRjYUTasXSuAAG2wJUtcBBGllCJuiElThVXIA5MTSZ7OHraYy3p8Q6HEABhVAAN2wBnwENDkoAVIgACrDbAWaoYRDoVAtZAoIGeY2IdUIEGW3CIKC4OVGCHSzz4OAPCCZ-xhXlcokwGggfnCkwMuk0rK5Juw9BItkewnd-kBoVg0U5V1fGLAE3eRFQOCIUvuzlqqAasAg-2C9Waq6TxioGgASTAW9EM5ROAIGhbbewnBRLqStuYgAIQfF8gAwpIAAKQwbBcHwQhCHrAAfqh4GIIAKKRQY0oggoa1CeMotbwognphHOZanpq2QCly17njRASetE9BgHAnghPgMAghyjDWuh4x7rm+aclQb5EXWmaesIbjiIQBIeqKAA+3J6vyPKcspy4iqonolI27ieMAMDkAiNQzuRx7cgul49sKq7BPQTY0Z86GbtuCI1vuh7eA+CBVuyVkaXyNG+TQ-nVkuBL2YxkKGYgxmmU+L4mu+GCfhUP6iO2nCJWZGCAV8cCSK0nAaiCwyeMRmZsQA7gmiaICmJw5mg1ZwMgMCeOUCWiB1Zattlf5SqgQKanofXoHKuaTSasDYPgDZxdCRnYLVJoAAqTfQyLpWiGhdkFxBwKSg6CjSI5ZJwlmqtZmlZDc6GTlu62iFtcDoIts5WfRILjuu7L7nqy0ttatr2hoL2bdthXOBRRInWSwaNc1ljmW1U5FpasDoNaM0ffQQlQBmZacogiicBAo1ceeeggLj-wGAtS2Tv2DNU1Q72fWlqJfhiiDdoSxB9nAZ1coyY4shimyBbdwUiqyuioJaLaC3dfKK7RhL2ZrystkO2kEsy4pPfFbOWoznPbQqFG-TRetwGrdta+yhrGqawQq3ABsGkaJrZLe7hWjadoOublvYFz+Cw0ecvC+Fi5e2rvYJ7ZJgS-6XsGxLyNhimWXtogtVdcMwRIDENAUGW3Ecvc3hFzAlqWsE0CUS057YFWNHhWAnqeOF0RQCzZv-LACD5rgCoREsbeakks+0ypvvu1kFkC0dfZkpwBsMvS44g54UKgPgnm7bzFSktA8AcqIuDXeY4Ugl9CNP+SrhxoSkZQPgb9K4K0Uri0AER6kpJxHyBAiKej8vq-UQEvN2-sRrfxPGeP68C-YeyXLA9B7sA4g2DuDB04CT40BjtAkw4BK7GTAAiSmH9AS0GwNQ2hLtd50jFJKNiVAazDAMNyShTCYgIlFFTJA+AaGoEkNEMAQkK5Vy4jxAwDwFpaCAA)

Comment: This is the best answer I've ever had! Thanks, allow me to call you Master @jcalz.